# Why to use Subject or BehaviorSubject in shared service, can't the same be achieved without observable?

Tags: angular

In angular to share data among component we use Shared Service with Subject or BrhaviorSubject observable like below,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    // Method to set navmenu //
    public sendData(data: boolean) {
        this.subject.next(data);
    }

    // Method to clear navmenu //
    public clearData() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    // Method to get navmenu //
    public getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

But we can achieve the same without using Subject or BehaviorSubject observable.
In the below example as the Component A and B both shares the instance of the EmailService, so if the component A change the value (emailService.apiKey) then the same reflect in the component B and vice-versa, like below,

```
class EmailService{
  public apiKey: string = 'ABCD1234';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  template: `
  Component A - {{emailService.apiKey}}
  <button (click)="changeApiKey()">Change Key</button>
  `
})

export class A{
  public emailService: EmailService;
  constructor(emailService: EmailService){
    this.emailService = emailService;
  }

  changeApiKey(){
    this.emailService.apiKey = "XYZ1234";
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'component-b',
  template: `
  Component B - {{emailService.apiKey}}
  <button (click)="changeApiKey()">Change Key</button>
  `
})

export class B{
  public emailService: EmailService;
  constructor(emailService: EmailService){
    this.emailService = emailService;
  }

  changeApiKey(){
    this.emailService.apiKey = "ABCD1234";
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `

    <component-a></component-a>
    <br />
    <component-b></component-b>
  `,
  providers: [
    EmailService
  ]
})

export class AppComponent {

}

Can someone please explain why most of the examples and tutorials use observable in shared service. What's the advantage in using that ??
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Subject` and `BehaviourSubject` are helpful in the case, when `component 2` wants to take some action based on the data change from `component 1` or vice versa

If you are not using any `publish/subscribe` patterns like `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`, then it is difficult to observe the data change and perform an action.

Answer (score 1):

There are few reasons why you want to use them. Overall you can inform components by

- Promises
- Events
- Observable

Lets take a look at all of them in brief:

- You can use `promise` but it has a drawback , you can only inform the `components` only once about the event. A promise is resolved only and once and then dies out.  Lets say, you are adding **products to a cart** , you can't use promise as it will happen multiple times.
- You can use events, something similar to what we had `$broadcast` and `$emit` in `angularJS`
- You have the `observables` which is also a type of events but comes with lot other features loaded with RxJs. You can use `switchMap()` , `mergeMap()` and so on.... . This is like evolved version of events in simple words.